# Section won't go full width in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

A section in the footer of a site I am working on will not go full width in IE8, I've tried virtually everything with no luck, I wondered if anyone else can spot something I've left out or done stupid.

http://mjtweaverdev.com/company/what-we-do/

Comment: Which section in the footer are you referring to?

Comment: Put the relevant code **in your question** please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 8 is a junk browser, no sane pc'er would use it nowadays so why would you be concerned how your page looks on that? My website looks like a joke on 8, great on anything else but not knowing what your footer is, asuming it's an image, use a resize tage on it. IE 8 is great to look at your html for errors, they show up there more prominately than others. Post your code for the footer so others can paste it in a demo to look